# shouldStartLoadWithRequest not being called

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

am trying to call shouldStartLoadWithRequest but its not being called and i have google it and found out that i have to set delegte to uiwebview

am using tabbar project

i have add

```
@interface MainView : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate
```

and

`[webview setDelegate:self];` in `viewDidLoad:`

but still not being called

please help

Answer (score 0):

a possible reason of the problem is that you could be loading HTML through loadHTMLString

EDIT:

I believe, if it's loaded from a string, there's no request therefore no shouldStartLoadWithRequest is never triggered.

I'm not sure if it's documented or not.

Comment: What does loadHTMLString have to do with things?  Is there anywhere in the docs that says if html is loaded with loadHTMLString that webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType: isn't going to be triggered?

Comment: If you are not calling loadHTMLString, how are you instructing the UIWebView what to load?

Comment: Forgive me, it's been almost a year since I worked with this issue myself. I'm not sure if it's documented or not. However from what I remember, if it's loaded from a string, there's no request therefore no shouldStartLoadWithRequest is never triggered.